# On matrix symmetries

Tags: matrices

Simple question, I think.  If a matrix $A$ is symmetric, then $A^T=A$.  If it is anti-symmetric, then $A^T=-A$. Suppose, more generally, $A^T=e^{iz}A$, where $z$ is restricted to be a real number.  How are such objects classified, named, etc?

Comment: As $e^{iz}A$ is complex in general, then $A^T$ is complex as well. For complex matrices it is more natural to consider the [Hermitian adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) matrix instead of the transposed one.

Comment: ... perhaps more common, but I don't believe that satiates question.

Comment: One reason for working with the Hermitian adjoint ( which is $A^{\ast} = \bar{A}^{T}$) is that normal matrices ( those matrices such that $A$ and $A^{\ast}$ commute) are well-studied with a well-developed theory. A matrix $A$ such that $\bar{A}^{T} = \lambda A$ for some complex $\lambda$ is normal.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson, thank you for your comment, but there are specific reasons I am not asking about the hermitian adjoint ...

Comment: OK, but perhaps you could share your reasons. Also, by the way, $e^{iz}$ can be any non-zero complex number if $z$ is suitably chosen.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson, Thanks for spotting that, I should restrict z to be real in my original question; I will edit. I'll have to get my specific reasons a little later.

Comment: There is no name, I think, and probably no classification (what does it mean to classify matrices?).

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I simply mean to analyze and explore theoretical properties, etc. And having no name would make it more difficult to have a vocabulary to discuss concepts within wouldn't it?

Comment: Answer provided by Rodrigo shows that condition  provided still implies $A$ is either symmetric or skew-symmetric; response accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

$$\mathrm A^{\top} = e^{i \theta} \mathrm A$$

then

$$\mathrm A = (\mathrm A^{\top})^{\top} = \left( e^{i \theta} \, \mathrm A \right)^{\top} = e^{i \theta} \mathrm A^{\top} = e^{i 2 \theta} \mathrm A$$

Assuming that $\mathrm A \neq \mathrm O$,

$$e^{i 2 \theta} = 1 \implies e^{i \theta} = \pm 1$$

and, thus,

$$\mathrm A^{\top} = \pm \mathrm A$$

In other words, if $\mathrm A^{\top} = e^{i \theta} \mathrm A$, then $\mathrm A$ is

- symmetric when $\theta = 2 k \pi$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$.
- skew-symmetric when $\theta = (2 k + 1) \pi$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$.

Other values of $\theta$ are not admissible.

Comment: Please explain to me where the error is.

Comment: You don't understand. Modulo $2\pi$, only two values of $\theta$ are admissible.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the conclusion that $e^{i\theta} = \pm 1$ is correct if $A$ is not the zero matrix.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson, could you elaborate?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Good point. I had forgotten about the case of the zero matrix.

Comment: $A$ is not generally symmetric or anti-symmetric to begin with.  This response is circular.

Comment: @user41431 No, it isn't.

Comment: Your statement literally says $A$ is symmetric/ skewed for certain values of $\theta$.

Comment: @user41431 And where is the circularity in there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48045/discussion-between-user41431-and-rodrigo-de-azevedo).

Comment: Misread a statement in proof at first; it is correct, and satisfies the question as I stated it; answer accepted.